# PhoneGap Build Push Notification Plugin Class not found Error

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the sample code on the new plugin for the push notifications for android on phonegap build.

I uploaded the code and when I run the apk on my test phone it gives me an error message: Error Handler Class not found.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your config.xml file to include a reference to the plugin so that phonegap build knows it needs to compile this in.

Comment: What is the configuration for config.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse choose Project->Clean. It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. In order for it to work you need to build the app and put it on a real device. I used the phonegap serve function to run my app inside the phonegap app on android, it doesn't work like that though.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2013, install the push plugin version 2.4. Going to Work! Also on the call of the method OnNotification add &Quot;window"

```
window.onNotification = function (and) {
```